# Use Strings as Keys in angular-translate - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I notice in all of the examples of angular-translate that they use translation ids like "errorMessage" as opposed to using the actual error message string like gettext does. Example:

`{{'errorMessage' | translate }}`

instead of

`{{'Uh oh, something went wrong!' | translate}}`

**Q** Why should/shouldn't one use the string as the actual translation id? It seems that it would improve readability and allow for easier translation of the resulting .json file.

Comment: What if you have to translate an entire paragraph?

Comment: @nicooga - As I see it, that would work just fine. Are you implying that there would be performance issues?

Comment: I don't think using an entire paragraph as a key for an object property is a nice idea.

Comment: It sounds counter-intuitive, yes; but is there actually a good reason against it? Also, after doing more research, I've learned of another library called angular-gettext that does more of what I'm looking for (strings as keys, gettext standards, etc...). It appears both libraries have their uses, but in my case I think angular-gettext will work better.

Comment: Looks good. You should put that as answer.

Comment: @nicooga, I would rather have the answer address the actual question. Why would it be a bad practice to use the strings as keys?