# Using of angular translate shows expression in Google search

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application, angular-translate

I'm using Angular-translate for a website I'm building. Unfortunately, I heard that Google does not compile pages when indexing them. Therefore, I only see the {{ '[elementName]' | translate }} expressions in Google. Does anyone know if there is a workaround ?

Comment: You could use more "index friendly" element names.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36852282/use-strings-as-keys-in-angular-translate-angularjs

Comment: Good idea ! But I would still see the curly brackets. It would be something like that : {{ 'This is the website title.' | translate }} instead of  {{ 'WEBSITETITLE' | translate }}

Comment: Use the directive instead of the filter.

Comment: Would it look like that : <p translate>Website title to be translated</p>